# Matching words from a library in one column and two shorter coulmn then merging these two data frames in r

Tags: r

I have a question regarding matching words from a library (my original data has 2000 rows) in one column to another column (13 rows). I am dealing with NA values and filling in for unequal rows. However, there are matching words so these should match up, whereas the words that don't match should be NA values.

I have example data.

```
df <- data.frame(words<-c("How","did","Quebec","nationalists","see","their","province","as","a","nation","in","the","1960s"))
df2 <- data.frame(library<-c("How","see","as","a","for","then","than","example"),
                  embedding1<-c(.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,.3,.46,.48,.53,.42),
                  embedding2<-c(.1,.5,.4,.8,.9,.3,.98,.73,.48,.56))
```

Here I try to match and merge the data with merge() the data

```
df<-merge(df, df2, all=T, na.rm=T)
```

I did not match the words to the column any suggestions on how to do this?

I want my data to look like this...

```
df4<-data.frame(words<-c("How","did","Quebec","nationalists","see","their","province","as","a","nation","in","the","1960s"),
                matched<-c("How",NA,NA,NA,"see",NA,NA,"as","a",NA,NA,"the",NA),
                embedding1<-c(.7,NA,NA,NA,.8,NA,NA,.9,.3,NA,NA,.6,NA),
                embedding2<-c(.1,NA,NA,NA,.8,NA,NA,.9,.3,NA,NA,.5,NA))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `by.x` and `by.y` parameters:

```
# merge data - full join
dd <- merge(x = df, y = df2, by.x = 'words', by.y = 'library', all.x = T) 

# add column from df
dd$library <- as.character(df2$library[match(dd$words, df2$library)])

print(dd)

          words embedding1 embedding2 library
1           How       0.50       0.10     How
2           see       0.60       0.50     see
3            as       0.70       0.40      as
4             a       0.80       0.80       a
5         1960s         NA         NA    <NA>
6           did         NA         NA    <NA>
7        Quebec         NA         NA    <NA>
8  nationalists         NA         NA    <NA>
9         their         NA         NA    <NA>
10     province         NA         NA    <NA>
11          the         NA         NA    <NA>
12       nation         NA         NA    <NA>
13           in         NA         NA    <NA>
14          for       0.90       0.90     for
15         then       0.30       0.30    then
16         than       0.46       0.98    than
17      example       0.48       0.73 example
```